# Failing to set COM+ ConstructorString on Win7 - CryptProtectData changes?

Tags: c++, windows, com, windows-7, com+

*UPDATED*

I'm trying to programmatic-ally set a COM+ component's ConstructorString with a value for later initialization.

The code in question works fine on WinXP, Win2k3, Vista and Win2k8.

I'm failing on Win7 - Home Premium version.

I've determined by trial and error that there seems to be a size limit on the constructor string - if the string is 512 characters (wchar) or less, it saves. Longer, and the SaveChanges call on the CatalogCollection object fails with a 0x80110437 - COMADMIN_E_PROPERTYSAVEFAILED error.

Turns out, all systems have that limit - 512 characters.

We use CryptProtectData to encrypt a password before putting it into the string.

On win7 (x64) the output of the string is longer than on XP (x32) and W2k3 (x64).

So - CryptProtectData has changed - why is the output longer?

```
    if (!CryptProtectData(&dataIn,L" ",&optionalEntropy,NULL,NULL,
    CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE | CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN, &dataOut))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you do with `dataOut` to turn it into a string? I can't remember the exact details now, but I assume the constructor string is a `BSTR`. `dataOut` is a byte buffer, so you need to be very careful when converting it to a string, so you don't trip on embedded NUL characters, etc.

Could you update your question to include the conversion from the output buffer of `CryptProtectData` to string?

Comment: dataOut was turned to a string by turning the byte buffer into a numeric string sequence.

I didn't write that part, but it looked like the byte was split into a powers of 16 character and a remainder character.

This was doubling the dataOut to twice it's length - thus running out of space.

I switched the code to use the ATL base64encode / base64decode calls instead - more efficient use of characters, and it fit inside of the string.

I'd rather not include the logic of the string - it is proprietary code, but I admit it was flawed.

Comment: Lucky guess on my part, glad it helped!